# JTree nodes not updated (in Scala)

Tags: java, swing, scala, jtree

I have an issue with the interoperability between **Scala** and the **Swing JTree component** (Java).

The JTree does not update correctly, except when I stop the display of the JOptionPane to prompt the user for the name of the new entity. This line is marked with [* * *]. As you can see, I have provided static text "xxx" instead, commenting out the call to the JOptionPane method. The JTree updates correctly as expected in this case.

I thought it might be something to do with the Swing threading model, but wrapping the update text in a Runnable class is not fixing the issue. See also [Why isn't my JTree updating when the TreeModel adds new nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831269/why-isnt-my-jtree-updating-when-the-treemodel-adds-new-nodes)

Why would the JOptionPane prevent the JTree from updating the nodes correctly?

I am doing it this way because Scala does not yet have a Swing Tree implementation that allows dynamic updates. See http://github.com/kenbot/ScalaSwingTreeWrapper

Any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Nigel

```
    import scala.swing._
    import javax.swing.{JOptionPane,JTree,SwingUtilities}
    import javax.swing.tree.{DefaultTreeModel,DefaultMutableTreeNode,TreePath}

    object XApp extends SimpleSwingApplication {

        val APP_NAME: String = "AppName"

        def getNameDialog(q: String): String = 
        { 
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(top.self, q, APP_NAME, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }

        def menuProjectNewX = {
            // Get the name of the X
            var name = "xxx"; // getNameDialog ("Enter the name of the X:")  [***]

            def doUpdate = new Runnable() {
                def run() 
                {
                    pl ("Running");

                    // Get the root
                    var root = treeModel.getRoot().asInstanceOf[DefaultMutableTreeNode]

                    // Insert new object
                    var newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(name)
                    treeModel.insertNodeInto(newNode, root, root.getChildCount())

                    // Expand the tree
                    var tp = new TreePath(newNode.getPath().asInstanceOf[Array[Object]])
                    tree.scrollPathToVisible(tp)
                }
            }

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doUpdate);
        }

        var tree: JTree = null
        var treeModel: DefaultTreeModel = null
        var flow: FlowPanel = null

        def top = new MainFrame {

            // Create the menu bar
            menuBar = new MenuBar() {
                contents += new Menu("Project") {
                    contents += new MenuItem(Action("New X...")     { menuProjectNewX })
                }
            }

            title = APP_NAME
            preferredSize = new Dimension (1000, 800)
            location = new Point(50,50)


            treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("(root)"))
            tree = new JTree(treeModel)
            //flow = new FlowPanel

            var splitPane = new SplitPane (Orientation.Vertical, new Component {
                    override lazy val peer = tree
                }, new FlowPanel)   

            splitPane.dividerLocation = 250
            contents = splitPane

        }    

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that every time the `JOptionPane` is shown, you're creating a new Frame, instead of reusing the MainFrame. Take in mind that `top` is a method, and when you refer to 'top' to show the `JOptionPane` you're creating a `new MainFrame`. So, at the end, you're adding the node to a tree that is in a MainFrame different from the one is being displayed.

One way to solve this is to simply store the MainFrame in a variable:

```
var mainFrame: MainFrame = null

def top = 
  {
    mainFrame = new MainFrame {
      // Rest of the code
    }

    mainFrame
  }
}

// To show the JOptionPane
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(mainFrame.self, q, APP_NAME, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Thanks very much... I didn't realise I was calling the defined method each time, instead of using a stored variable. :-/ Cheers!